# Make lightbox effect close on image click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [this lightbox effect](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/):

I have tried for hours, but no luck. How can I make the lightbox image close on the click of the image, instead of using the x or the overflow space.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey mate! Could you show your code?

Comment: Why do you want to close the lightbox on close of the image? You can click outside the container and the lightbox will also close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in lightbox.js, after line 126 (after: `appendTo($('body'));`)

```
  $('.lb-nav').hide().on('click', function(e) {
    _this.end();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You put me on the right track. I changed it to .lb-image instead of lb-nav and got it working. Thats for your help.

'$('.lb-image').hide().on('click', function(e) {
    _this.end();
    return false;
  });'

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$lightbox.find(".lb-loader, .lb-close").on("click",function(){return i.end(),!1})}
```

find this line, and paste .lb-nav after two classes:

```
this.$lightbox.find(".lb-loader, .lb-close, .lb-nav").on("click",function(){return i.end(),!1})}
```